# Is this bad kerning, or is there a space missing?

Tags: kerning

Is the space (or lack thereof) between "Date" and "in" bad kerning? What can I implement to make that more readable?

[image]

Comment: For "what to implement" you'll need to tell us in what this text is. Is it on web, an app, in something like InDesign or Photoshop, etc? Or is it just pixels in an image file like a PNG or GIF?

Comment: @user568458 It's a label in .net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks very likely to be dodgy character spacing to me. It's not just the kerning either side of that space - most of it looks too tight (e.g. the `Exp`), and the `e-i` gap is wider than the `e-l` gap in Panelist.

As for what to do, I know nothing about .net so can't help there, .net is well outside the standard design tools so you'd be better off asking a site with .net users, but in general these are the things to look for:

- If it's live text, look for a `tracking`, `character spacing` or `letter spacing` control. Since the tracking (spacing between *all* characters) is tight everywhere, I'd try to widen it everywhere rather than adjusting the kerning for just that gap.
- If it's just a pixel image, the best you can do is damage limitation. Open it in an image editting app, drag a selection box around everything from the `i` onwards, and nudge it all a pixel to the right. It'll still be too tight but at least it'll be readable

Answer (score 0):

This font is not spaced correctly you should space the entire font manually.
Good examples are is in **Home** between the **h** and the **o** in comparison to **expiry** between the **e** and the **x**.